# Alternative to CTRL + C of macOS Terminal in Sublime Text 3

Tags: macos, terminal, keyboard, shortcut, sublimetext

On macOS terminal <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> terminates the program running. In Sublime Text, <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> runs a program such as Python, Ruby or such.

If I want to terminate a running code, what is the shortcut key in Sublime Text 3 equivalent of <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open **Key Bindings** from **Preferences** of Sublime Text or short cut is (**cmd ⌘** + **,**) and add like:

```
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+c"], "command": "cancel_build" },
]
```